# Class design if two class needs to exchange information

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-4.0

If I have two classes as

```
class A
{
}
```

and

```
class B
{
}
```

`class A` wants to use methods of `class B` and vice-versa.

What should be the best design other than the mediator pattern?

Comment: Why not the mediator pattern? (I'm not sure that's the right pattern here, but why the objection?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the minimum, you should decouple your classes with interfaces. This way your intended contract between the two classes would be captured explicitly through the interfaces.

```
interface IA {
    // Methods for use in class B...
}

class A : IA {
    private readonly IB b;
}

interface IB {
    // Methods for use in class A...
}

class B : IB {
    private readonly IA a;
}
```

Other than that, it depends a lot on the nature of interaction that you are planning.